# Google Compute and OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, google-compute-engine

Does the Google Compute Engine support OpenGL 2.0+?

Have been trying to run a program that seems to be having issues due to this lack of support I believe.

Is there any way around this at all?

Comment: Why are you trying to use a cloud computation service in combination with a library for local rendering of images in the first place?

Comment: Who said anything about images?

There are many things or uses I may be doing with it.

All I need is a simple yes or no answer...

Comment: @Tealc: "*Who said anything about images?*" You did. When you mentioned OpenGL. Which is a *graphics library*; it's right there in the name. Oh sure, you can make it do computational stuff, but that is not its *purpose*.

Comment: @Tealc did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think, the only way to get the support of OpenGL is by adding a gpu to your google cloud engine instance. You can follow this doc to add it: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus

Comment: Necessary perhaps, but not sufficient. Here a n1-standard-4 (4 vCPUs, 15 GB memory) with added "NVIDIA Tesla P100 Virtual Workstation" GPU and "Turn on display device" apparently has no OpenGL. GPUtest closes immediately after launch. Device Manager shows Google Graphics Array (drivers up to date) and 3D Video Controller (drives missing and unavailable from web).

Comment: Update. Google's P100 provides OpenGL... but V1.1 only. Likewise it's K80. I have found no other GPU options on Google VMs.